# iOS custom font in a referenced folder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, fonts

My custom font from a referenced folder is not in font families and cannot be used. When I use a normal group instead of a referenced folder everything works perfectly. My `Info.plist` is correct, I have the proper copy bundle resources in the build phases (the referenced folder is there and not every file in it). I also use the proper PostScript name in `[UIFont fontWithName]` but it just returns `nil`.

When I check my main bundle, the font file is there in the simulator/device and I can read it without a problem. The only problem is that the `UIFont` does not see it. When I list font families, my custom font is not there.

This problem occurs only when I have my custom font in a referenced folder or in a custom bundle (which is also a referenced folder). When I put the font in a normal group everything works. I tried cleaning the project, uninstalling the app and also resetting the iphone simulator. This same problem happens when I build from Xcode 4.6 and Appcode 2.1. I am building against iOS 6.1 SDK.

I went through all the tips and tricks about using custom fonts in iOS and the only difference is the referenced folder. I want my resources in a referenced folder (or a custom bundle) because I create resources (shader/textures/...) in other programs and I just want to copy them to the folder and not add them one-by-one to Xcode.

What could be wrong with my approach? Or is this a known bug/limit of the build system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fount the solution when solving another problem (missing icons, when moved them into a referenced folder/custom bundle).

The solution to this problem is to **use the whole path to the custom fonts in the plist file** (the whole relative path within the project's directory). In my case it looks like this:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>mybundle.bundle/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>mybundle.bundle/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf</string>
</array>
```

When using Xcode's "graphical" representation of the plist, just enter the whole path with the file name there.

When using other resources from a referenced folder/custom bundle e.g. images for button icons and setting them in the code, also use the whole path and not just the image's name e.g.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybundle.bundle/images/cancel.png"]
```

instead of just

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of Xcode.  I had the same problem not too long ago.  I am hoping that eventually XCode comes out with a packaging or collection option that repackages your code in pretty folders the same way cocoa pods does but for now we're stuck.

Comment: it looks like a limitation of the underlying build system, because AppCode behaves the same. i hope apple will fix their mess with groups/folders some day. i will wait a bit more and if no one gives a better answer i will accept yours. thanks.

Comment: I found the solution for this problem, check my answer.